# Cannot remove selecteditem in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a DataGrid that bound a List of contacts:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionChanged="LoadContactInfo" 
          x:Name="ContactsGrid"
          ...
```

The user can select an Item (contact), and the method `LoadContactInfo` will firing, this method load the information of the `SelectedItem`.

Now each item, have a checkbox, when the user press it, the contact will be deleted from the `Contacts` collection. All working well, but there is a problem, in particular the `DataGrid SelectedItem` will switch to the next contact available in the collection.

I tried to fix this situation removing the `SelectedItem` in the `LoadContactInfo` event:

```
Contacts.SelectedItem = null;
```

but I've also the same problem, how can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove a DataGrid row just assigning a null value.

But you can do that through the Rows property and call the Remove method.

```
var selectedItem = ContactsGrid.SelectedItem;
ContactsGrid.Rows.Remove(selectedItem);
```

It's cool check if the selected item is not null before.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I doesn't have `.Rows` property, why?

Comment: @MrFantastic Sorry, i'm confused. Try the 'Items' property

Comment: I already remove the contact from the ItemSource, but the DataGrid switch the selectedItem to the next.

Comment: @MrFantastic You should set some negative value to the SelectedIndex property.

Answer (score 0):

if you use ItemsSource property, it will be better to remove item from your data.
Contacts should implement INotifyCollectionChanged or be an ObservableCollection. Try to set SelectedIndex to -1.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
ContactsGrid.UnselectAll();
```